# how to insert username and check user name is duplicate in database

Tags: java

```
public static ArrayList<User_Database> getUsername() {

    ArrayList<User_Database> list_Username = new ArrayList<User_Database>();
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        String sql = "SELECT user_name FROM users";
        Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        Statement state = connect.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = state.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            String user_name = rs.getString("user_name");
            User_Database userDB = new User_Database(user_name);
            list_Username.add(userDB);
            System.out.printf(" %s  \n", user_name);
        }
        rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return list_Username;
}

public static void createNewUser(User_Database us) {
    getAllUser();
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        Statement state = connect.createStatement();
        String sql = "INSERT INTO users  VALUES (0, '" + us.user_name + "' , '" + us.user_password + "' , '"
                + us.email + "') ";
        if (getAllUser().equals(us.user_name)) {
            System.out.println("Username not available");
        } else {
            state.executeUpdate(sql);
            state.close();
            System.out.println("Insert Database Success");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: very easy just put your mind in your code.

Comment: please tell me i'm just amatur

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `getAllUser()` and I don't know what is does. Let's suppose that you want to call `getUsername()` instead, which is the method that you present here and that returns all the usernames that you have in your DB in an `ArrayList<User_Database>`.

When you do `if (getAllUser().equals(us.user_name))` you're trying to compare an ArrayList with a String, which is wrong. Please, find the correction to your code bellow:

```
public static void createNewUser(User_Database us) {
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        Statement state = connect.createStatement();
        String sql = "INSERT INTO users  VALUES (0, '" + us.user_name + "' , '" + us.user_password + "' , '"
                + us.email + "') ";

        boolean isUnique = true;

        for(User_Database user: getUsername()) {
            if(user.user_name.equals(us.user_name)) {
                isUnique = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!isUnique) {
            System.out.println("Username not available");
        } else {
            state.executeUpdate(sql);
            state.close();
            System.out.println("Insert Database Success");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**Other notes**

- Close your statement outside the try catch block, e.g. inside a finally block. This way you ensure that even in the occurence of an exception it will be closed.
- Don't forget to close the connection too.
- Try to not directly insert the information given by users in your queries, since it can lead to serious problems in your DB (e.g., [SQL Injection](https://www.journaldev.com/2489/jdbc-statement-vs-preparedstatement-sql-injection-example)). Try to see [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) and use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead.

**Another important consideration:**

- Since you're checking for the uniqueness of usernames, an ArrayList might not be the best (in terms of performance) to achieve what you want, since you have to go through it when you want to check if there is already a username in your DB or not (O(N)). Instead, try to get all usernames and put them in a [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html). With set, you just have to try to [add](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add(E)) the username to it; you will get a true if username is unique or false if it is already in the set (O(1)).

Hope it helped.